# PrimeFaces Autocomplete Error Rendering View

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Buenas necesito algo de ayuda con un error que me arroja el `autocomplete` de `Primefaces` cuando introduzco las letras, he copiado el ejemplo directamente de su pagina y no me muestra la lista y me dice este error

> GRAVE [http-nio-9090-exec-4]
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException
>   Error Rendering View[/AgregarCine.xhtml]

Codigo .XHTML

```
        <form id="formNuevoCine">
            <div class="WebGrupo">
                <div class="WebGrupoHorizontal">
                    <div class="WebSubGrupoHorizontal">
                        <label class="WebLabelHorizontal"> Nombre del cliente: </label>
                        <p:autoComplete value="#{agregarCineBean.nombreCliente}" completeMethod="#{agregarCineBean.AutoCompletadoListaCliente}"/>
                    </div>
```

Java Bean "agregarCineBean.java"

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AgregarCineBean implements Serializable {
String nombreCliente;
    /*AUTOCOMPLETADO*/
    public List<String> AutoCompletadoListaCliente(String query) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            results.add(query + i);
        return results;
    }
    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return nombreCliente;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }
}
```

Este es mi pom de Maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.AAAAA</groupId>
    <artifactId>AAAAA</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AAAAA Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Faces Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Faces Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate 4.3.6 core library library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate 4.3.6 JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring LDAP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JasperReport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--ICONOS FONT AWESOME-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencies for Eclipse JPA Persistence API -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: ¿Y no te muestra el stacktrace de la excepción? Por cierto, los métodos en Java **siempre** tienen que estar en "camelCase" (empezar por minúscula y poner las iniciales en mayúscula)

Comment: Una cosa que está mal es que en JSF no se usan directamnte `<form>` sino que se usa `<h:form>`. Muy bien podría ser el problema, pero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolverlo pero ha decir verdad no vi donde estaba la solución pero en efecto había algo en las declaraciones que me afectaba y lo que hice fue rehacerla pagina otra vez pero copiando los datos desde otra pagina que esta perfecta y en efecto ahora si muestra bien el autocomplete.